# Can anybody help me to make space between the letters in a column?

Tags: spacing, color, multirow

I try to make the table same as the image but texstudio highlights  me errors in the compilation. I hope anyone of the masters can help me with comments especially in the use of \multirow and how to accommodate the first  column. 
[image: it is the table i want to do]

> ```
> \documentclass[headsepline=true,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,x11names,DIV=10]{scrbook}
> \usepackage{typearea}
> \usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names, table]{xcolor}
> \usepackage{rotating}
> \usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
> \usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}
> \usepackage[backend=biber,date=short,style=apa,apabackref=false]{biblatex}
> \DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
> %\usepackage[nomarginpar, margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}
> \addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
> \usepackage{bera}
> \usepackage[berasans]{quotchap}
> \colorlet{chaptergrey}{SkyBlue}
> ```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Tables

>

```
     %\usepackage{lmodern}
>     \usepackage{xspace}
>     \usepackage{xkeyval}
>     \usepackage{array,caption,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
>     \captionsetup{labelfont=sc,textfont=it}
>     \usepackage{longtable}
>     \usepackage{ltablex}
>     \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
>     \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
>     \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
>     %\usepackage{totcount}
>     \usepackage{makecell}
>     \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont}
>     \usepackage{boldline}
>     \usepackage{cellspace}
>     \addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
>     \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
>     \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
> 

>     \appendix 
>       \clearpage % o \cleardoublepage
>       \addappheadtotoc
>       \appendixpage
>     
>       
>     \printbibliography 
>     \backmatter
>     \appendix 
>     \include{anexo1}
> 
> 
> 
> 
>     \chapter[Anexo 1]{Clasificación para los marcadores discursivos de reformulación y ejemplificación}
>     
>     \begin{longtable}[c]{|c|p{5cm}|p{8cm}|p{1cm}|}
>       \caption[anexo1]{Clasificación para los marcadores discursivos de reformulación y ejemplificación} \label{tab:inst1}
>        \hline
>      \multirow{5}{*}[-8em]{\begin{sideways} Reformulación \end{sideways}}  & \multirow{5}{3cm}{\textbf{Explicación:} Casado
> (1991) considera el término \enquote{explicación} en el sentido de
> \enquote{evidenciación} [del latín \textsc{explicare}
> \enquote{desplegar, desenvolver}].} & \textbf{Profundización:} El
> segundo miembro ahonda en lo que establece el primer enunciado. No se
> trata de decir lo mismo, sino de darle una índole más aguda, ya sea en
> su denotación o en su connotación. \par Los reformuladores que
> evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: o sea, es
> decir, en otras palabras, (0) más bien, vale decir. & \\ 
>     \cline{3-4}
>     & & \textbf{Rectificación:} \enquote{Sustituye[n] un primer miembro, que presentan como una reformulación incorrecta por otra que
> la corrige, o al menos la mejora} (Martín \& Portoles, 1999:4126).\par
> Los reformuladores que evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus de
> análisis son: o sea, es decir, en otras palabras, esto es, en este
> sentido, así, (o) más bien. &  \\ 
>     \cline{3-4}
>     & & \textbf{Equivalencia:} Ambos enunciados son correspondientes. La diferencia entre ellos es de significante, no de significado. En
> palabras de Casado, \enquote{no se establece jerarquía entre los
> segmentos, que constituyen dos formulaciones igualmente válidas}
> (Casado, 1991:108). \par Los reformuladores que evidencian esta
> función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: o sea, es decir, en otras
> palabras, esto es, vale decir. & \\ 
>     \cline{3-4}
>     & & \textbf{Ejemplificación:} Se procura una \enquote{particularización del enunciado anterior luego de un marcador
> del tipo [como] por ejemplo} (Fuentes, 1996:62). \par Los
> reformuladores que evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus de
> análisis son: o sea, es decir, (como) por ejemplo, a modo de ejemplo,
> a saber. & \\
>     \cline{3-4}
>     &\multirow{5}{3cm}{\textbf{Generalización:} Se refiere a una función discursiva que busca situar un enunciado o un grupo de estos
> en relación con algún elemento que lo instaure en un orden
> determinado.} & \textbf{Evaluación:} El segundo miembro no solo retoma
> o modifica lo anterior, sino que también hace una apreciación de este,
> comunica un juicio. \par Los reformuladores que evidencian esta
> función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: es decir, en este sentido,
> así, (o) más bien, en el fondo, en general. & \\ 
>     \cline{3-4}
>     & & \textbf{Recapitulación:} \enquote{Presenta[n] su miembro del discurso como una conclusión o recapitulación a partir de un miembro
> anterior o de una serie de ellos} (Martín \& Portolés, 1999:4133).
> \par Los reformuladores que evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus
> de análisis son: o sea, es decir, en otras palabras, en definitiva, de
> esta forma, así, (o) más bien, en el fondo, recapitulando, por lo
> tanto, en conclusión, a modo de conclusión. & \\ 
>     \cline{3-4}
>     & & \textbf{Denominación:} \enquote{Se identifica con un hiperónimo o con su designación precisa a un grupo o una enumeración
> emitidos antes del marcador discursivo} (Fuentes, 1996:61). \par La
> autora llama a esta categoría \textbf{etiqueta}, sin embargo, nos
> pareció más adecuado este otro término. \par Los reformuladores que
> evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: es decir,
> en otras palabras. & 
>     \hline
>     \end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't compilable as the `longtable` is missing several `\\` (line break) instructions. Fixing this issue, getting rid of two entirely unnecessary (and counterproductive) `\multirow` wrappers, providing a bit more structure to the table (such as using raggedright instead of full justification, since the columns are fairly narrow), and simplifying the preamble to leave in only the code that's actually needed for the table leads to the following result (I hope this is roughly what you're looking for):

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[headsepline=true,paper=letter,headings=big,
bibliography=totoc,x11names,DIV=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage[berasans]{quotchap}
\colorlet{chaptergrey}{SkyBlue}

\usepackage{array,caption,multirow,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc,textfont=it}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\appendix

\chapter[Anexo A]{Clasificación para los marcadores discursivos de reformulación y ejemplificación}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|c|P{5cm}|P{8cm}|P{1cm}|}
\caption[anexo1]{Clasificación para los marcadores discursivos de reformulación y ejemplificación} \label{tab:inst1}\\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\endlastfoot

\multirow{40}{*}{\begin{sideways} \Large Reformulación \end{sideways}}   
& \textbf{Explicación:} Casado (1991) considera el término \enquote{explicación} en el sentido de \enquote{evidenciación} [del latín \textsc{explicare} \enquote{desplegar, desenvolver}]. 
& \textbf{Profundización:} El segundo miembro ahonda en lo que establece el primer enunciado. No se trata de decir lo mismo, sino de darle una índole más aguda, ya sea en su denotación o en su connotación. 
\par 
Los reformuladores que evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: o sea, es decir, en otras palabras, (0) más bien, vale decir. 
& \\ 
\cline{3-4}
& & 
\textbf{Rectificación:} \enquote{Sustituye[n] un primer miembro, que presentan como una reformulación incorrecta por otra que la corrige, o al menos la mejora} (Martín \& Portoles, 1999:4126).
\par
Los reformuladores que evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: o sea, es decir, en otras palabras, esto es, en este sentido, así, (o) más bien. 
& \\ 
\cline{3-4}
& & \textbf{Equivalencia:} Ambos enunciados son correspondientes. La diferencia entre ellos es de significante, no de significado. En palabras de Casado, \enquote{no se establece jerarquía entre los segmentos, que constituyen dos formulaciones igualmente válidas}
(Casado, 1991:108). 
\par 
Los reformuladores que evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: o sea, es decir, en otras palabras, esto es, vale decir. 
& \\ 
\cline{3-4}
& & \textbf{Ejemplificación:} Se procura una \enquote{particularización del enunciado anterior luego de un marcador del tipo [como] por ejemplo} (Fuentes, 1996:62). 
\par 
Los reformuladores que evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: o sea, es decir, (como) por ejemplo, a modo de ejemplo, a saber. 
& \\
\hline
&\textbf{Generalización:} Se refiere a una función discursiva que busca situar un enunciado o un grupo de estos en relación con algún elemento que lo instaure en un orden determinado. 
& \textbf{Evaluación:} El segundo miembro no solo retoma
o modifica lo anterior, sino que también hace una apreciación de este, comunica un juicio. 
\par 
Los reformuladores que evidencian esta
función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: es decir, en este sentido, así, (o) más bien, en el fondo, en general. & \\ 
\cline{3-4}
& & \textbf{Recapitulación:} \enquote{Presenta[n] su miembro del discurso como una conclusión o recapitulación a partir de un miembro anterior o de una serie de ellos} (Martín \& Portolés, 1999:4133).
\par 
Los reformuladores que evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: o sea, es decir, en otras palabras, en definitiva, de esta forma, así, (o) más bien, en el fondo, recapitulando, por lo tanto, en conclusión, a modo de conclusión. 
& \\ 
\cline{3-4}
& & \textbf{Denominación:} \enquote{Se identifica con un hiperónimo o con su designación precisa a un grupo o una enumeración emitidos antes del marcador discursivo} (Fuentes, 1996:61). 
\par 
La autora llama a esta categoría \textbf{etiqueta}, sin embargo, nos pareció más adecuado este otro término. 
\par 
Los reformuladores que evidencian esta función en nuestro corpus de análisis son: es decir, en otras palabras. 
& \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hello @Mico I have a question! why did you use \multirow{40}{*}? thank you very much,

Comment: @Sheltis - Because, in my view, it's easier and more straightforward than `\multirow{5}{*}[-8em]{...}`.